# How to add a close button (X) to this overlay?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Hi I am using a Jquery code from 
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/07/framewarp-jquery-plugin/

Its all working fine except that the X botton on the top right conner for closing the page is missing! How can I add it back on???

Comment: Probably going to need to see YOUR code.

Comment: Please display your code and maybe elaborate on what you have tried or an image of what you want to achieve please. Anything to help us help you... We cannot work off nothing, and a link to a 3rd party site is nothing. Do some footwork and show us some code and maybe a jsfiddle.net/ for us to work from?

Comment: did you tried my answer or do you have any problems?

Answer (score 0):

you can see the close button on section Message Passing (blue)

```
<a onclick="frameWarp.hide();" id="close" class="button2" href="#">Close Window</a>
```

there you can insert an image

change your css for example to this:

```
#close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

and the link to this:

```
<a href="#" id="close" onclick="frameWarp.hide();"><img src="../images/close.png"></a>
```